# Copy on steroide incompatible

Tags: android, plugins, intellij-idea, copy

I'm using Android Studio and I want to copy my code keeping the highlighting of my text. I found this plugin for IntelliJ Idea : https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7198 (copy on steroide) but when I try to install it I've got this error :

> "Following plugins are incompatible with current IDE build : 'Copy' on
>   steroide"

Does someone know how to fix it? Or know another plugin to copy text with colors?

Thank's in advance !

Answer (score 0):

["'Copy on steroids' plugin functionality is bundled with the platform now - available for testing in IDEA 14 EAP."](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-67767#comment=27-758381)

It works out of the box in Android Studio 1.2

Comment: What do you mean by out of box? (Sorry I'm not a native speaker)

Comment: That you do not need to install, enable or configure anything, it just works. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_the_box_feature